# Get image url from message in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

i'm trying to get the url of image when i do the command +coin but I d'ont know if I do it right.
if someone can help me i'll very appreciate it.

```
@Bot.command()
async def coin():
  print(message.attachments[0].url)
  await ctx.send("work")
```

Comment: have you test this on your bot does it give you any errors?

Comment: yes , i get this error
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ofekl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 690, in _parse_arguments
    next(iterator)
StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
discord.errors.ClientException: Callback for coin command is missing "ctx" parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your close for that to work you first need to get the ctx
in your function like this then you need to get the URL that the user sent. The way that I would do it is like this.

```
async def coin(ctx):
```

This will create the function.
Then it is simply getting the rest of the code set up for that image.

The rest of the code should look like this

```
print(ctx.message.attachments[0].url)
await ctx.send("work")
```

Here is an example of the full code:

```
@bot.command()
async def coin(ctx):
  print(ctx.message.attachments[0].url)
  await ctx.send("work")
```

Comment: but i want to add image , no link

Comment: Changed it for your code

Comment: thank you !!!!!